# use query and subquery in querybuilder in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

i use simple code mysql and me cant generate this code to querybuilder
please help me

```
SELECT *
FROM `sites` AS s
WHERE s.`quantity` > 0 AND s.`status` = 1 AND (SELECT count(`visitsite`.`id`)
                                               FROM `visitsite`
                                               WHERE `visitsite`.`site` = s.`id` AND
                                                     `visitsite`.`createdate` > '2016-10-25 00:00:00'
                                              ) < (SELECT `quantity`
                                                   FROM `limitviewday`
                                                   WHERE `limitviewday`.`id` = s.`limitviewday`)
```

Comment: can you add your entities class pls?

Comment: Give us more detail about issue? What happend ?

Comment: i have 2 table one table `sites` and another table `visitsite` table 2 is visit of `site`and relation many to one bitween table one and table 2, 
and table `limitviewday` is relation in by `site`